# How do I view helm's install message again?

Tags: helm

I installed something with `helm install`, and it output advice in the form of a message on the console for things I would want to do. How can I again get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Getting the helm notes

You must first find the name of the release, for that you can use `helm list -A`

```
❯ helm list -A
NAME        NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                       APP VERSION
kubeapps    kubeapps    1           2023-07-31 13:57:09.698002603 -0500 CDT deployed    kubeapps-12.4.8             2.8.0      
my-release  default     1           2023-07-31 15:17:46.534953551 -0500 CDT deployed    nextcloud-3.5.20            27.0.1     
traefik     kube-system 1           2023-07-30 17:06:33.680339822 +0000 UTC deployed    traefik-21.2.1+up21.2.0     v2.9.10    
traefik-crd kube-system 1           2023-07-30 17:06:32.239719019 +0000 UTC deployed    traefik-crd-21.2.1+up21.2.0 v2.9.10
```

Then you can the get the notes by using the name and namespace (argument to `-n`),

```shell
helm get notes -n default my-release
```

Note, `-n default` is the default, and not strictly required.